# django form always not valid

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm using ajax to send data to my view, the goal is to post comments without refreshing the page

the problem is that the form always returns false when checking if valid or not, I cant find the problem hope you can help me

when i submit the form it return result:"" because the form is invalid

so I printed comment_form.errors and it looks like the data is empty

`<ul class="errorlist"><li>content<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>question<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>`

my View

```
def question_detail(request, slug):

    question = get_object_or_404(Question, slug=slug)

    allcomments = question.comments.all()

    comment_form = CommentCreateForm()

    return render(request, 'question/question_detail.html', {'question': question, 'form': comment_form, 'comments': allcomments})

def add_comment(request):

    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentCreateForm(data=request.POST)
        print(comment_form.is_valid())
        
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            print('hi')
            user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            result = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content')
            user = request.user
            user_comment.author = user
            user_comment.save()
            return JsonResponse({'result': result, 'user': user.username})
        else:
            print('anything')
    return JsonResponse({"result": ''})
```

my template

```
                <form id="commentform" data-question="{{question.slug}}" class="commentform" method="POST">
                    <legend class="border-bottom fw-bold">Add a Comment</legend>
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <select name="question" id="id_question" class="d-none">
                        <option value="{{question.id}}" selected="{{question.id}}"></option>
                    </select>
                    <label>{{form.parent.label}}</label>
                    {{form.parent}}

                    {{form.content}}
                    <button type="submit" value="commentform" id="newcomment"
                        class="newcomment btn btn-primary col-12 mt-1">Post</button>
                </form>

    $(document).on('click', '#newcomment',' #newcommentinner', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    let button = $(this).attr("value");
    // let slug = $('#commentform').attr("data-question") 
    let csrftoken = $('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
    // let patch = "{% url 'question:question_detail' 0 %}".replace(0, slug)
    console.log($("#commentform").serialize())

    var placement = "commentform"
    if (button == "newcommentform") {
      var placement = "newcommentform"
    }
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"{% url 'question:add_comment' %}",
        data:{
            'data': $("#" + button).serialize(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken,
        },
        cache:false,
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json)
        },
        error: function(xhr, errmsg, err){
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: the default method of a view is get method so in your function return only when method is post , so when in your browser call this view will return the error you get

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis I updated the question can u have a look

Comment: When you try to post the comment some field is empy and in  the Comment model that empty field  is required so you have to check that the posted data contains all the required fields for your model

Comment: @DimitrisKougioumtzis the data is empty only  when I send it to the view thats why the form wont validate, but it is there in the ajax function when i console.log it

Comment: when you click the button to post the data via the ajax function  check that you post the correct data that the form uses

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but will get a guide

```
def add_comment(request):
   if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
     comment_form = CommentCreateForm(request.POST)
     print(comment_form)
     if comment_form.is_valid():
        user_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
        result = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content')
        user = request.user
        user_comment.author = user
        user_comment.save()
        return JsonResponse({'result': result, 'user': user.username})
  return JsonResponse({"result": ''})
```

Comment: nice that worked, but now I realized that it never enters the "if comment_form.is_valid():",, the form is always not valid idk

Comment: about form validation read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: i cant find the problem of why the form is not valid.. can you have a look on the code